# Excel Hyperlink function sending me to the wrong URL

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I've made this formula:

=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",1,"https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir",Table6[Post Code])," ","+"),$A$1&"/","Tesco+Superstore,+Kipling+Drive,+Mickleover,+Derby/"),"Break/",""),"Google Maps Route")

The idea is to create a google map from a list of post codes (with a trip to the courier at Tesco in the middle). It works really well, no matter how many postcoes I put in, it opens Google maps and comes up with a route.

However, it only ever brings up the route as it was when I first created the formula. If I hover over the cell, the link is the old link. However, if I get rid of the "Google Maps Route" at the end, so it just shows the link, it's the correct, new link. I have to copy and paste values, into another cell, and then click on that cell to bring up the new route.

So the formula works, it's just not refrshing in some way. F9 doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share us with some screenshots, I test your formula with replacing "Table6[Post Code]" with a range, the link when you hover over the cell shows url content ends with theTEXTJOIN combination results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Calculation Options of Formulas is set to "Manual". If so, please change it to "Automatic"

You will see this option in "Formulas" on the top ribbon, then "Calculation Options" - in there, choose" Automatic". See image below for reference.

[Screenshot of what to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS2sc.png)